# MySQL - Update tables if id exist or not

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update two from different tables:

```
$query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a ,".$SupportUserTable." b 
SET a.ticket_status=0, 
    b.solved_tickets= CASE WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.solved_tickets+1) ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
    b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' AND b.assigned_tickets>=1 THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,
    a.ticket_status='0' 
    WHERE a.enc_id=? AND b.id=a.operator_id";
```

But this works only if b.id exist otherwise it doesn't do anything, but my aim is to update however the tick `a.ticket_ststus`.
 I have tried to use `OR` instead of `AND` but it returns a duplicate key error or it updates the wrong `b.assigned_ticket`.
Thanks in advance
EDIT
Thanks for the information,I have tried something like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE a
        SET 
            b.solved_tickets= CASE WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.solved_tickets+1) ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
            b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' AND b.assigned_tickets>=1 THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,
            a.ticket_status=0
        FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ".$SupportUserTable." b
        ON b.id=a.operator_id
        WHERE a.enc_id=? ";
```

but it says that there is an error before `FROM ".$SupportTicketsTable." a`, but I don't understand what it wrong

Comment: You need to use an *outer* join.  See [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: @eggyal I'm sorry for the stupid question, but should I use `full outer join`?

Comment: No. MySQL does not have FULL OUTER JOIN. It can be simulated, but it's not what you want. MySQL supports two kinds of OUTER JOIN; LEFT [OUTER] JOIN and RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN. The OUTER keyword is optional and frequently ignored. For every LEFT JOIN there is (apparently) a logically identical RIGHT JOIN. So it's up to you which you use but I will note that SO presently records 2016 instances of RIGHT JOIN being used as compared with 44,062 LEFT JOINs, so that might be a hint. ;-) Another useful trick is to construct the SELECT first and then figure out how to rewrite it as an UPDATE.

Comment: You're not respecting UPDATE syntax

Answer (score 0):

Solved(thanks for the help):

```
 $query = "UPDATE ".$SupportTicketsTable." a
                LEFT OUTER JOIN ".$SupportUserTable." b
                ON b.id=a.operator_id
                SET 
                    b.solved_tickets= CASE WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' THEN (b.solved_tickets+1) ELSE b.solved_tickets END , 
                    b.assigned_tickets= CASE  WHEN a.ticket_status!='0' AND b.assigned_tickets>=1 THEN (b.assigned_tickets-1) ELSE b.assigned_tickets END ,
                    a.ticket_status='0'
                WHERE a.enc_id=? ";
```